# LINQ GroupBy with SQLite.EF6 results in 'APPLY joins are not supported' exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sqlite, group-by

I have the table `VersionedEntities` that looks like this:

```
+----+--------------+---------+
| Id | Name         | Version |
+----+--------------+---------+
| 1  | FirstEntity  | 1       |
+----+--------------+---------+
| 2  | SecondEntity | 2       |
+----+--------------+---------+
| 1  | ThirdEntity  | 3       |
+----+--------------+---------+
```

`Version` is the primary key.

`VersionedEntity` class:

```
[Table("VersionedEntities")]
public class VersionedEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public long Version { get; set; }
}
```

I want to select the latest version of each `Id`, resulting in this:

```
+----+--------------+---------+
| Id | Name         | Version |
+----+--------------+---------+
| 2  | SecondEntity | 2       |
+----+--------------+---------+
| 1  | ThirdEntity  | 3       |
+----+--------------+---------+
```

I already have a working query when using `Microsoft SQL Server` as database:

```
List<VersionedEntity> versionedEntities;

using (var dbContext = _createDbContext())
{
    versionedEntities = dbContext.VersionedEntity
        .GroupBy(versionedEntity => versionedEntity.Id)
        .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(versionedEntity => versionedEntity.Version).FirstOrDefault()).ToList());
}
```

I want to use SQLite as database instead, but when using SQLite the above query results in an `NotSupportedException` with the message: `APPLY joins are not supported`.

What I have found out is that only `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is implemented in SQLite ([source](https://sqlite.org/omitted.html)). I guess that LINQ `GroupBy()` is using one of the not implemented joins.

I would like to know if there is a workaround to this, or if I could rewrite my query to something that is SQLite compatible.

Comment: Might be worthwhile here to create an indexed view and query that instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could suggest the following alternative query which should translate to `NOT EXISTS` criteria based SQL query:

```
var result = db.VersionedEntity
    .Where(e => !db.VersionedEntity.Any(e2 => e2.Id == e.Id && e2.Version > e.Version))
    .ToList();
```

It's just a different interpretation of the requirement - select the record if there is no other record with the same `Id` and bigger `Version`.

Comment: Thanks - It works! It is of course a quick fix. Not being able to use GroupBy() limits the possibilities of queries... I'll mark your answer as accepted answer for now. Again, thank you.